# Android - how to toggle background color of list item from transparent to red periodically?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a listview I'd like to manipulate by toggling the background colour of each listitem from transparent to red every 5 seconds. This is the code for my getView method in a custom `BaseAdapter`:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        // store my view in view holder here

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  
    }

    // How do I manipulate this so that the background colour toggles
    // between TRANSPARENT and RED every 5 seconds ?        
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    return convertView;
}
```

What I am looking to do is toggle the background color of each list element using a `Timer` that provides periodic execution. But how exactly does this need to be implemented ?  Or perhaps is there a more optimal way of achieving the same result ?

Comment: @ Der Golem - Yes you are right, the feature itself can be highly annoying but I was trying to experiment with timers applicable on list items. This is just an experiment. I was thinking of using Timers, but I was wondering about how to cancel the Timers when an item gets recycled or goes out of view.

Comment: as im busy i cud only say the easiest wud be creating repeating animation where you change the background every 5 second otherwise if you create countdowntimer then for each item one object and that too a recursive kinda function which wud definetly slow down your scroll speed ... animation i guess is the best suited here....

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

You could start this `CountDownTimer` inside your `ListView` for each row that you create.

Comment: Thanks for this. If my understanding is correct, I would also have to cancel the timers when a listitem goes out of view (the recycling phenomenon in Android listviews). I am wondering about the best way to achieve this as well.

Comment: @user1841702 I have not tested this myself, but this was my initial thought of how to tackle your problem. I would try this out, and see what happens.

Comment: @user1841702 Actully, I think this will still work. What will happen when the application re-use the rows, is that a new `CountDownTimer` will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background `Thread`( to evoid main UI `Thread` blocking when there's a huge numbre of ListItems ) in which you create a periodic `Timer` and once a period is finished you can look over all the `ListView` items and change the background color : `listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(color);`

Here's an example :

```
    CountDownTimer remainingTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(futureInMillis, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO: restart counter

                futureInMillis = newTime(); // set the same futureInMillis to make it periodic
                this.start();
                listView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        }.start();
```